# How to add text to PyQt QcalendarWidget

Tags: pyqt5, qpainter, qcalendarwidget

How does one write into the QCalendarWidget cell? In python, I keep getting painter not active message. Can someone help me out with this?

```
qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
qp.setPen(QtGui.QColor(168, 34, 3))
qp.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Decorative', 10))
qp.drawText(rect, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, 'hello') 

rect = QtCore.QRect()
date = QtCore.QDate.fromString('2020-01-01')
calendar = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self)

calendar.paintCell(qp, rect, date)
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must inherit from `QCalendarWidget` and overwrite the `paintCell` method.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt, QRectF, QDate
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QPainter, QColor, QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCalendarWidget, QApplication

class CalendarWidget(QCalendarWidget):

    def paintCell(self, painter, rect, date):
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        if date == QDate(2020, 1, 1):
            painter.save()
            painter.drawRect(rect)
            painter.setPen(QColor(168, 34, 3))
            painter.setFont(QFont('Decorative', 10))            
            painter.drawText(QRectF(rect), Qt.TextSingleLine|Qt.AlignCenter, str(date.day()))
            painter.drawText(rect, Qt.AlignCenter, 'Hello\nWorld') 

            painter.restore()
        else:
            QCalendarWidget.paintCell(self, painter, rect, date)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = CalendarWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! But I already have calendar as part of the MainWindow (not a popup), and initialize it as I run the application. I will need to read from it as well as write to it - could I still draw/paint on it?

Comment: Ok, I see. Created a class, as suggested, attached it to the tab, as  `self.calendar_2 = CalendarWidget(self.ui.tab_2) `, now, how do I pass parameters to it, as date and text specifically? Any way to do it?

Comment: Ok, figured that out too. Now question, how do I save the day's number in that cell. It appears to be over-written by the text.

Comment: Ok, got it now. Thanks.